# How do I play audio when my ios app starts?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I have been following tutorials and looking at other posts but I can't seem to get audio to start playing automatically when my app starts.

I want the wav file to just keep playing in the background and looping. I do NOT want start and stop controls etc...

Below is the code I have in my ViewController.m file (is this the right place?) and I have added the AVFoundation.frameowrk and imported it to my .m file. Additionally I have added my wav file called AlienRoom to my supporting files. Any help would be awesome! I am new so please go step by step or make it real clear if you can. Thank you!!!

p.s. I haven't added the code to make it loop so any help there would be great too!

```
//play background sound upon opening app

-(void) awakeFromNib

{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AlienRoom" ofType: @"wav"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: u want to play the sound while apps wake from sleep ? or just the first app load ?

Comment: Any time the main view appears I would like the background audio to be playing continuously. So on first opening or returning to this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement **AVAudioPlayerDelegate** in **ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

**ViewController.m file**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"AlienRoom" ofType: @"wav"];
   if(!self.theAudio)
       self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
   self.theAudio.delegate = self;
   [self.theAudio play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)data successfully:(BOOL)flag{

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(playAudioAgain) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}

- (void)playAudioAgain{

   [self.theAudio play];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if(self.theAudio.isPlaying)
   {
        self.theAudio.delegate = nil;
        [self.theAudio stop];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are you saying to put that code in my ViewController.h file? I tried it there and in the .m but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what are alll the things that u r doing after loaded ViewController.h ? displaying another view ? present model view or any other ?

Comment: In my ViewController.h I am declaring a bunch of IBOutlets and IBActions and that's it. Just labels and buttons pressed stuff.

Comment: check the latest answer.If u have any issues, check the audio file "path"

Comment: Thanks for the help. My only question is where exactly is all this code going. Are you saying put all this code in my VIewController.h or some of it, or maybe the AppDelegate.h??? If you could say this goes in this file this goes in this file it would be easier for me to understand. I have tried a few different things...

Comment: please place all the code in VIewController.m.. plz check the edited code

Comment: I had never declared a property before but I figured it out and now I see you posted it! It worked! Thank you for all the help I definitely just learned a lot! Is there a way to adjust the level of the volume of the wav file through the code? (it's louder than my other sounds)

Comment: ur most welcome.. you can set the volume through self.theAudio.volume = urValue. , ranging from 0.0 through 1.0.